# remove a word from url using htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I wanted to remove a word from my URL given below

`http://servername/plan/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)`

New URL should be like `http://servername/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)`

Basically i want to remove Plan from URL for which i have written htaccess which is replacing plan with index.php given below

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]

RewriteRule ^(.*)/plan/(.*)$ /$1/$2 [L,R=301,QSA]
```

Can any one help me with this

Thanks in advance

Comment: No it is not a directory.. it is a method of my controller